# AngularJS Routes Not Functioning As Intended

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AnguluarJS Routes to navigate between the page of my application. The issue that I am having is that going straight to the web address and having Angular redirect you to where you are supposed to go works as intended, but when you go straight to the route, it doesn't function and instead just loads the template rather than loading it within the index page.

Here's my code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Kita 2 -- Alpha</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/css/foundation.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/style.css">
  <script src="vendor/js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>

  <base href="/">
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('app/img/bg.png')">
  <div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div class="container-fluid">
              <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
              <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Course Catalog Demo</a>
              </div>

          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Subjects <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Mathematics</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Science</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Social Studies</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Heathful Living Education</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  <div id="view" ng-view></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

});

app.controller("HomeController", function($scope, AuthenticationService) {
  $scope.title = "Awesome Home";
  $scope.message = "Mouse Over these images to see a directive at work!";

  $scope.logout = function() {
    AuthenticationService.logout();
  };
});
```

and lastly, home.html:

```
<div id="home">
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Cras sit amet nibh libero</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Vestibulum at eros</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="list-group">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">Cras sit amet nibh libero</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Vestibulum at eros</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```

TL;DR: Going to foobar.com directs to foobar.com/home and displays home.html's content within index.html like it us supposed to, but going straight to foobar.com/home just displays home.html's content, and I'd rather have it displayed within the `ng-view` area of index.html.

Comment: If I understand, foobar.com/home is an actual web location different from foobar.com .  Usually Angular is used for single page apps, which means all app code must be at a single URL location.  Try using anchors instead of actual directories.  Like this: foobar.com/#home .

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using "Foobar.com/home"... As long as HTML5 mode is enabled and the server will have a catch all route... (Note that HTML5 mode will fallback to Hashbang mode for older browsers)

Comment: How are you serving index.html and home.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like JeffryHouser said, that is not possible with angularJS, at least in a very simple way. Since angularJS is used for SPA, foobar.com/home should be foobar.com/#/home. Your application is just one page, which is your index.html.

If you want to use html5mode, then you have to write all rewrite rules for your server so that it points all requests to index.html. But this has to be done outside of angularJS, but on the server-side, whatever your server is. (ex. apache, nginx, or node)